# vsftpd login error: 530

Tags: centos, ftp, fedora, vsftpd

I'm running the vsftpd ftp-server on Fedora Server 22.
The problem is, if a user try to login with a correct password, the following error occurs: "530 Login incorrect."

`vsftpd.conf` :

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=management
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/mnt/ext/users/$USER
chroot_local_user=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
virtual_use_local_privs=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
hide_ids=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
ftpd_banner="Welcome..."
```

`pam vsftpd file` :

```
auth required pam_pwdfile.so pwdfile /etc/vsftpd/passwd
account required pam_permit.so
```

`pam_pwdfile.so is installed` :

```
/usr/lib/security/pam_pwdfile.so
```

`passwd file` (Tried with both generated with "htpasswd" and "openssl":

```
user:hash
```

/mnt/ext/users and subdirectories are owned by user "management"

Have somebody an idea what I can do, I've switched some days ago to fedora on the server from archlinux, and on arch I had managed to get it working.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/386531/why-wont-vsftpd-let-me-log-in-with-a-virtual-user-account.

Next, I'm not sure what you meant under "passwd file (Tried with both generated with "htpasswd" and "openssl":"

'passwd file' changes a password of the user 'file'... So, you probably need to use a command from an answer on superuser:

```
sudo htpasswd -c -d -b /etc/vsftpd/passwd user password
```

Comment: I meant, that I've generated the "/etc/vsftpd/passwd" file with the "sudo htpasswd -c -d -b /etc/vsftpd/passwd user password" command, and it did'nt worked. And I also generated it with "openssl passwd -1" and it also didn't worked. I've already seen the http://superuser.com/questions/386531/why-wont-vsftpd-let-me-log-in-with-a-virtual-user-account question, and it didn't helped.